# How to disable ubuntu automount or change automount owner

Tags: ubuntu, automount

If there is partitions, ubuntu will auto mount it to /media/?????.
root is the default user and group id.
How can I change its user and group id? or disable automount, instead add entries to /etc/fstab.

Answer (score 1):

Add this command to your `/etc/init.d/rc.local` file:

```
sudo mount -t vboxsf H_DRIVE /media/windows7share
```

From:
http://www.sysprobs.com/virtualbox-shared-folders-ubuntu-1010-guest-windows-7-host

Answer (score 0):

Just add the filesystems to `/etc/fstab`.